# SASS Mixin: only apply hover style if class is on a link?

Tags: sass

I'm attempting to set a bunch of background colours using a mixin. I'd also like to apply hover styling to these background colours IF the classes are assigned to a link element:

```
@mixin bg-color($color) {
   background-color: $color;
   &[ifthisisalink] {
     &:hover {
        background-color: darken($color, 10%);
     }
   }
}

   .bg-blue {
      @include bg-color(blue);
   }
```

So if we have `.bg-blue` on a plain div, there is no hover color. But if `.bg-blue` is on a link, there is a hover color:

```
<div class="bg-blue">Hover on me and nothing happens.</div>
<a href="#" class="bg-blue">Hover on me and I go darker.</a>
```

Is this possible in SASS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `@at-root`:

```
@mixin bg-color($color) {


 background-color: $color;
    @at-root {
       a#{&} {
          &:hover {
             background-color: darken($color, 10%);
          }
       }
    }
 }

 .bg-blue {
    @include bg-color(blue);
 }
```

Comment: WOnderful. Thanks!